# Getting delete accounts in participants in the channel

Tags: telethon

I have 2.7k members in my channel, how can I get deleted accounts from all these members? I tried iter_participants, get_participants, getparticipantsrequest, but they all return max 200 members, and I can't find all deleted accounts. also, if you specify offset in getparticipantsrequest, then 201 participants are not returned.